Edge browser closes immediately after opening URL using Selenium in Python
I am trying to automate a task using Selenium with the Edge browser.
However, after running my script, the webpage opens and then immediately closes. I tried using  #time.sleep() to keep the browser open for scraping, but the page still closes after a few seconds. Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this issue?
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options

website = 'https://website.com'
path = r'C:\msedgedriver.exe'

# Create an instance of Options
edge_options = Options()

# Create an instance of Service with the path to the driver
service = Service(executable_path=path)

# Launch the browser using the service and options
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service, options=edge_options)
driver.get(website)

# Close the browser (optional)
driver.quit()


In python selenium, once the program is executed driver object is terminated resulting in closing of the browser. To avoid this, you need to detach the driver object and browser by adding the following line of code:
# Create an instance of Options
edge_options = Options()
edge_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

Ps: Make sure to comment out driver.quit() line.
Refer this answer to know more about detach options.

If this has resolved the issue you should accept the answer. What should I do when someone answers my question?

Please note that this is a default behavior, Selenium will close the browser after completing all operations. I used the code you provided to test, but it did not exist when I introduced "import time" and added the appropriate time (maybe need to add more seconds). I also tested the code snippet provided by Shawn, which can also keep the browser open, you can also refer to it.
